# How to parse the http request using typebox?

Tags: node.js, express, typebox

I am using the typebox validator

```
import { Type } from '@sinclair/typebox';
import { Value } from '@sinclair/typebox/value';

const metaReqSchema = Type.Object({
  name: Type.String()
});
const reqSchema = Type.Object({
  // You can also type querystring, headers and response
  params: Type.Object({
    idParam: Type.String()
  }),
  body: metaReqSchema
});
@httpPost('/version/:idParam')
  public async getMeta(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    try {
      const dataInputValidated = Value.Decode(reqSchema, request);

      console.log('iNPUT vALDIATED', dataInputValidated.body);
      console.log('Param', dataInputValidated.params);

      return response.status(200).json({
        data: 1
      });
    } catch (err) {
      return response.status(500).json({
        data: err
      });
    }
  }
```

Getting this error :
`Converting circular structure to JSON\n    --> starting at object with constructor 'Socket'\n    |     property 'parser' -> object with constructor 'HTTPParser'\n    --- property 'socket' closes the circle`

While validating just request.body or request.parse, it works
I need validated input from the request object which maps to the input type.

But decoding gives same object as the request.

````
try {
      const dataInputValidated = Value.Decode(metaReqSchema, request.body);

      console.log('iNPUT vALDIATED', dataInputValidated);
      console.log('Param', dataInputValidated);

      return response.status(200).json({
        data: dataInputValidated
      });
    } catch (err) {
      return response.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
    }
    ```


This works but valdiating the reqSchema it throws circular json error
````

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to store whole response object which is complex data structure and contains circular dependencies as it stated in error message (TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON)

What you should do is either you map the data you need instead of storing whole circular object.